# How can I revert specific files of a commit?

Tags: git, git-revert

I have pushed a commit that modified files file1, file2, file3, file4, file5.
I have decided that the logic is wrong and as part of the commit I modified some APIs in files2,file3.
What I want to do is somehow revert the changes localy for files2,files3 and and fix the rest of the files correctly.
So start my fix having as base the original version of the files2,files3 but the latest of the rest.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easiest way to do this:**

```
# get the version of the file from the given commit
git checkout <commit> path/to/file
```

**In my case:**

```
git checkout b1cdc80fffe381eb3938e7b7f337d6550ffbd199 /MyProjects/AndroidCameraAPI/app/src/main/java/info/androidhive/androidcameraapi/MainActivity.java
```

Then modified my code and did the commit again.

**NOTE:** The commit has I have used in my example was the stable version, in which I wanted to revert back.

Comment: So check out the version of the file before my commit. And after finishing push?

Comment: Why when I do the checkout the file is staged already for commit?

Comment: Yes it will staged for commit. At that stage you can make your required changes and commit again. Or if you want to make it more clean, then after checking out to the previous commit, create a new local branch. Do your modification. Then commit and push to the remote branch.

Comment: What I am doing is I did a RESET on the files so became unstaged. And now I am working on this. Is this ok?

Comment: You don't need to unstage the file. Staged file means it can be commited to the working branch.

Comment: In one file I need to do a minor modification. In the other the original. So it is fine the way I do this right? RESET the one with the modifications, then add etc

Comment: Yes, its fine. You can go for it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to soft reset your commit (this will keep the changes in your files but not committed). Discard the changes for the files2 and files 3 (this will set them back to the previous commit).

[Git reset documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

Comment: What do you mean soft reset?I have pushed my commit and there are others on top of it now

Comment: I see. In that case you might want to check out the previous commit to your changes. Add a new commit with the original files2 and 3 and cherry pick them: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Comment: Why cherry pick? Sorry I am not very well versed with git